# android sqlite insert into where

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to insert category of the application of the existing table of application data. I do not know if im doing it correct, but in what i am doing i get this error as well.

how should i do it correctly?

**Mainactivity**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Please Select Category of : " + AppName); 
    builder.setItems(shareItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String itemz = String.valueOf(shareItems[item]);
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insertcategory(AppName, itemz);
                }
            });
    AlertDialog shareAlert = builder.create();
    shareAlert.show();
```

**Handler**

```
 public long insertcategory(String AppName, String itemz) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor crack = sqlitedb.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + KEY_CATEGORY
                    + " VALUES ( ' " + itemz + " ' ) WHERE " + KEY_NAME
                    + " LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + AppName+ "%" });
            return 0;
        }
```

**updated query**
This is what i used to update the table. itemz gets the value as 'Game' but it does not getting updated

```
public long insertcategory(String AppName, String itemz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, itemz);
        return sqlitedb.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
                new String[] { "%" + AppName + "%" });

    }
```

Table created as

```
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table "
            + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_NAME
            + " text not null, " + KEY_PACK + " text not null, " + KEY_PERM
            + " text not null, " + KEY_LEVEL + " text not null, "
            + KEY_CATEGORY + " text);";
```

Comment: As you can see there is an error in your SQL query. As a first aid print out your generated SQL query and execute it directly in SQLlite. There is a good way to find your mistake in your real source code.

Answer (score 7):

The INSERT command does not have a WHERE clause because it inserts a completely new record.

It appears you want to set/change the value in an existing record.
This would be done with an UPDATE command:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET category = 'Entertainment' WHERE name LIKE ?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `INSERT INTO` then use `WHERE` clause.

INSERT INTO means you're adding a new row in a table, which doesn't exist before.
You can use WHERE on UPDATE and SELECT statement but not on INSERT INTO.

I'm guessing you mean UPDATE instead of INSERT INTO:

Try this:

```
public long insertcategory(String AppName, String itemz) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor crack = sqlitedb.rawQuery("UPDATE " + KEY_CATEGORY
                    + " SET yourFieldNameHere = ' " + itemz + " '  WHERE " + KEY_NAME
                    + " LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + AppName+ "%" });
            return 0;
        }
```

For insert, try this:

```
   public long insertcategory(String AppName, String itemz) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Cursor crack = sqlitedb.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + KEY_CATEGORY
                        + " VALUES(' " + itemz + " ')" });
                return 0;
            }
```

Change yourFieldNameHere with the name of your table's field.

Comment: hey thank you alot. and for the knowledge, i was running after something false.

Comment: But this does not add up the data in to my database

Comment: It won't add if the row doesn't exist yet.  What UPDATE statement does is to update the existing record if there's any.  See my updated answer for the code for INSERT INTO. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use WHERE in INSERT INTO. If use INSERT will added a new row. If you need update row which KEY_NAME LIKE "%AppName% use UPADATE